# How to extract variables from tab_model in R to create new data frame?

Tags: r, sjplot

[Example output of tab_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haJnd.png)

I have created a table from `tab_model` that includes multiple models and wish to extract all 'p-values' and 'Estimates/Odds Ratio' to create a data frame that includes these. Output of tab_model is an html file. I am unable to find a function to pull this info in accordance, any ideas on how I could do this?

For example, I want to retrieve all p-values and Estimates for variable 'age' in all of my models...Only 3 in example image but I have hundreds

Comment: It would be better if you had an example dataset and would describe your question to this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get these values from the regression models themselves, instead of outputting them to a HTML-table, and *then* extract them.

Without further knowledge of your process and data it is difficult to provide a more concrete answer.